# Zend_Translate & Zend_Cache standalone

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-translate, zend-cache

I'm trying to add `Zend_Translate` in a PHP project, using Zend components as standalone libraries.

I'm already using cache for several items using the following method:

```
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory( ...
if (!($obj = $cache->load('OBJ')))
{
  $obj = ...
  $cache->save($obj);
}
```

Now, following the documentation of `Zend_Translate`, I set the same `$cache` object to my `Zend_Translate` with a `setCache` before to actually create the object:

```
Zend_Translate::setCache($cache);
$translate = new Zend_Translate(
  array(
    'adapter' => 'gettext',
    'content' => 'languages',
     null,
     array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME)
  )
);
```

So, here I'm steering away from my usual method which instead would have been to put the whole `Zend_Translate` in the cache. The overall result, as of now is the following:

```
// 1.php

ob_start();
session_start();

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory( ...
if (!($obj = $cache->load('OBJ')))
{
  $obj = ...
  $cache->save($obj);
}

Zend_Translate::setCache($cache);
$translate = new Zend_Translate(
  array(
    'adapter' => 'gettext',
    'content' => 'languages',
    null,
    array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME)
  )
);

echo $translate->_("Hello, I'm the first script");

// end 1.php
```

and

```
// 2.php

ob_start();
session_start();

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory( ...
if (!($obj = $cache->load('OBJ')))
{
  $obj = ...
  $cache->save($obj);
}

Zend_Translate::setCache($cache);
$translate = new Zend_Translate(
  array(
    'adapter' => 'gettext',
    'content' => 'languages',
    null,
    array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME)
  )
);

echo $translate->_("Hello, I'm the second script");

// end 2.php
```

This approach doesn't work as I see that the cache files are created every time that I load the page.

I am wondering:

1. Am I correct to assume that I need to call `Zend_Cache::factory` in every page?
2. How can I get my translate to work with cache in this standalone situation?
3. Question about `Zend_Translate`: does `addTranslation` add anything to the picture or can I just load all my translations like I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question #1**  Yes. You need to call Zend_Cache::factory on every page load. But if you already use Zend_Cache you can re-use it for your needs instead of creating a new instance for Zend_Translate.

**Question #2**. There is no difference in usage of Zend Translate + Zend Cache as standalone components. Here is how I use them as standalone components in such small scripts:

```
// Init application
define('APP_PATH',      realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
define('APP_DATA',  APP_PATH . '/lang');
define('APP_CACHE',     APP_PATH . '/tmp');

require_once 'Zend/Translate.php';
require_once 'Zend/Cache.php';

// initialize cache
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory(
      'Core'
        , 'File'
        , array(
              'caching'     => true
            , 'lifetime'    => 900
            , 'automatic_serialization' => true
            , 'automatic_cleaning_factor'   => 20
            , 'cache_id_prefix'             => 'Translate'
            )
        , array(
              'hashed_directory_level' => 0
            , 'cache_dir'   => APP_CACHE
        )
    );

// Setup translation object
Zend_Translate::setCache($cache);
$translate = new Zend_Translate('tmx', APP_DATA . '/general.tmx');

echo $translate->_("Hello, I'm the second script");
```

OK, you are ready to use Zend_Cache. All caching will be covered by Zend_Translate instance itself internally.

**Question #3**. addTranslation() just adds new translation sources, you can pass them to constructor instead (your case).

Try to set "cache_id_prefix" for cache before passing it to Zend_Translate, that will help you to determine if problem occurs somewhere in your code "..." or new cache that is created on each page load is created by Zend Translate.

Answer (score -1):

If I recall correctly, Zend_Cache usage in Zend_Translate is a bit of a misnomer. I think what it does is reduce directory scanning and locale setup by setting the options for the Translator, not the results of the translation strings themselves.

Comment: Please provide a comment on the reason for the down vote. Thanks.